# Is the use of Timestamp as a RowKey in Azure Table Storage justifiable?

Tags: azure-table-storage

For my schema, I can choose a good partition key, but unfortunately, I don't have anything unique within the partition. So I decided to use DateTime property as a RowKey in the following manner:

`RowKey = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfffffff");`

Is this use justifiable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use DateTime as **RowKey**, that's a reasonable design. You can also consider using inverted ticks `string.Format("{0:D19}", DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks)` which sorts in reverse date and time order, so you can easily retrieve the most recent *n* entities within a **PartitionKey**.

To see further details, you can check "Log tail pattern" in [Azure Storage Table Design Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-design-guide#log-tail-pattern).